# ui-router without the hash '#' in Angularjs 1.2.24

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Problem Question-

Currently my URL appears like `http://localhost/app/public/index.html#/login`. But now I am trying to remove '#' from it but it keeps on breaking and fails to load the resources. I looked around for the solution but nothing works.

What I have tried so far:

```
<base href="/"> in my index.html
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); in my app.js 
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!'); (This after above did not worked)
```

Someone how it does not work at all. Any one knows what is happening?

Update 1- Directory Structure

```
-ProjectName
 -public
  -src (Controllers and views)
  -styles (CSS)
  -vendors
   --scripts (Angualrjs and other vendors)
  -index.html (main index file where all files links are mentioned as <script src="vendor/scripts/angular.js"></script>)
  -app.js
```

Comment: Which resource does it fail to load? What's their URL, and where are they located?

Comment: please see my updated question :) It fails to load everything from CSS to Angularjs and throwing 404 not found.

Comment: You didn't provide the code, but your base is `/`, and the URL you use is `vendor/scripts/angular.js`, so the URL where it looks for angular.js is `/vendor/scripts/angular.js`. And angular.js seems to be in fact at `/app/public/vendors/scripts/angular.js`

Comment: somehow its not playing well. As you suggested now I provide the full path as such my base href <base href="../public/">. And this solve the problem of resources, but now I have other problem of " "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". After doing some research it is coming from this line $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);. Here is other post on same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092724/angularjs-throws-typeerror-cannot-read-property-indexof-of-undefined. Any idea ?

Comment: Here is a working [example of HTML5 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26009350/1679310). If server is set properly, you can check there how to...